# How to optimize a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, indexing

I'm looking for a way to improve the performance of a table. Below is the MySQL table.

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| receiver | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| depCode  | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sms      | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| billable | varchar(5)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| smsc     | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sendDate | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sendTime | time        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

It has got more than 10,000,000 records.

Below is a SQL query I used to fetch the records. `${variable}` is the syntax for the variable.

```
SELECT count(*) as totalCount FROM `tbl_incoming` 
WHERE `depCode`=${depCode} AND `smsc`=${smsc_value} AND receivedDate BETWEEN  ${fromDate} AND ${toDate} 
ORDER BY receivedDate, receivedTime;
```

Please see the EXPLAIN below.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `tbl_incoming`  
WHERE `depCode`="Slrd" AND `smsc`="dgsm" AND receivedDate  BETWEEN  "2009-11-26" AND "2014-11-26"  
ORDER BY receivedDate, receivedTime;

+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_incoming | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 542527 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

According to my knowledge indexing can help to improve performance of a table.

*PS : I'm looking for other options as well except indexing.*

How can I improve the performance of the table?

Comment: have you tried an index?

Comment: @Sathya I'm looking for other options as well. Not only indexing. That's why this not a duplicate. I think you don't have to mark this as "closed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes should help you.

Here in your query, you are having a where condition on columns depCode, smsc AND receivedDate. You must be having more knowldge about the data. 
First identity the column which have the most number of distinct values among the above 3. Choose it for index column and add the other 2 in include.

```
Eg:
Create Index IX_Custome On tbl_incoming (depCode) Include (smsc,receivedDate)
```

This is just an approach, ignore if not useful.